# opening a new tab loses the arraylist in local storage javascript stack overflow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, web-storage

My application work tries to store some data on my local storage which works fine when i am not opening any new tab or window, but when i open a new tab, my array loses all its previous stored data and stores only the current data. Please suggest what i am doing wrong here.

my code is something like this:

```
getCurrReqIdList = [];


localStorage.setItem('getCurrReqIdList', JSON.stringify(getCurrReqIdList));

var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem('getCurrReqIdList');
var getFinalReqIdList = JSON.parse(retrievedData);

if(getFinalReqIdList.length > maxCurrentConnectionLength) {
  console.log('Hello');
  getFinalReqIdList.shift();
  getCurrReqIdList.shift();
  localStorage.setItem('getCurrReqIdList',JSON.stringify(getFinalReqIdList));           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post is a bit confusing, but I bet you have the lines

```
getCurrReqIdList = [];
localStorage.setItem('getCurrReqIdList', JSON.stringify(getCurrReqIdList));
```

running every time you load your page, for initializing the store. So when you open a new tab, it loads the page and override the local storage value with an empty array.

You page should run something like:

```
getCurrReqIdList = localStorage.getItem('getCurrReqIdList');
if(getCurrReqIdList) {
     getCurrReqIdList = JSON.parse(getCurrReqIdList);
} else {
    getCurrReqIdList = [];
    localStorage.setItem('getCurrReqIdList', JSON.stringify(getCurrReqIdList));
}
```

Comment: it says .. Cannot read property 'length' of null when i execute the getCurrReqIdList = localStorage.getItem('getCurrReqIdList');

Comment: thanks a ton.. its working ... , there was some mistake on my part... cheers! .. :)

Answer (score 0):

It should not happen so because data stored in localStorage object will be shared between tabs also.

You might have some other code which will reset or delete the data from localStorage as soon as you open a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

According to: **[This](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage/issues/252)**

you can't share data between multiple tabs using sessionStorage, because a new page is a new session.

You need to replace

```
setStorageType('sessionStorage')
```

by

```
setStorageType('localStorage') // which is default
```